# How to create a post template with two sidebars

Tags: templates, sidebar

I'm looking for a way to have a post template that has two sidebars, one on the right side, the other on the left side, with always the same content on each one of them.

I defined that left sidebar as "sidebaraleatorio", and right sidebar as "sidebarrecomenda", and created for each one of them a .php file, then I registered them in my functions.php of child theme. After that, I created a template trying to call the two sidebars php files:

`<?php get_sidebaraleatorio(); ?>
<?php get_sidebarrecomenda(); ?>`

But when I tested, there were several bugs, so I guess something is wrong in my way of doing it... Shouldn't I create different sidebar php files?

If the problem is not that, I can include the other code I'm using on these files

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `sidebar-sidebaraleatorio.php` and `sidebar-sidebarrecomenda.php` sidebar templates to your (child) theme directory, you can then call them with [`get_sidebar()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sidebar/) function.

Like so `get_sidebar('sidebaraleatorio);` and `get_sidebar('sidebarrecomenda);`.

You can read more about sidebars from the [Developer Handbook > Sidebars](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/sidebars/#displaying-sidebars-in-your-theme).

Comment: Thanks Antti. Just to clarify, I should add this get_sidebar function to the template file I am creating? Besides that, I still need to registered them in my functions.php, right?

Comment: @usina Yes, you can use `get_sidebar` in your template files. If you want to have dynamic sidebars / widget areas in your sidebars, then you should register sidebars in your functions file, too. I think `get_sidebar()` only includes the sidebar template file, so it can have either static and/or dynamic content.

Comment: Hi Antti. Thanks, this procedure is indeed working. But another related question. If I want to have an extra sidebar, besides the one that comes with my theme, should I use get_sidebar in my sidebar.php file as well as creating a new one? What I did was 1. Create a new secondary-sidebar.php 2. Register it in functions.php 3. Add a widget to it via WP frontend 4. Call it via get_sidebar in index.php. But it did not work. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you

Comment: @usina You need to add the `get_sidebar()` function for your custom sidebar to every page template where you want to display it. E.g. singular / single / page / archive.php, unless index.php is the only template file you have in your theme.

Comment: I am trying to add it to a single post, so in single.php, after `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` I added another line `<?php get_sidebar( 'secondary' ); ?>`. Instead of pulling the sidebar, when I opened the post it returned an error of layout saying that website is under technical difficulties. Should I substitute or just add another line for this new sidebar in index, single and other places as well?

Comment: @usina You could enable WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_LOG on your wp-config.php, load the page again and then see debug.log on wp-content to see what is causing the error. Make sure there's no php errors on the sidebar template file and it is named as sidebar-{sidebar-name-here}.php.

Comment: Thanks my friend. It had an extra endif tag. I removed it and now it's working!! Thank you so much